# how can i loop through array of objects from firestore (array union objects)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, frameworks

I have a comments array field that has two objects in the firestore database.

[image]

it returns this in the console:

[image]

I have tried to loop through the array with the code below, but with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<ion-card style="margin-top: 10px !important;" *ngFor ="let comment of comments">   
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of comment?.comments">
       <div style="color: black"><h6>{{item?.comment}}</h6></div>

    </ng-container>
</ion-card>
```

TS:

```
comments: any = [];

getData(){
  this.route.data.subscribe(routeData => {
    let data = routeData['data'];
    this.comments = [];
    if (data) {
      this.item = data;
      this.image = this.item.image;  
      this.comments.push(this.item.comments)
      console.log( this.comments ) 
    }
  })   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you should do like this:

```
<ion-card style="margin-top: 10px !important;" *ngFor="let comment of comments">   
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of comment">
       <div style="color: black"><h6>{{item?.comment}}</h6></div>

    </ng-container>
</ion-card>
```

So `comment` instead of `comment?.comments` in the inner loop.